# conversion of List to Array in python

Tags: python-3.x

In Below code I am trying to `count` the value of `e` ....if `count` value is greater than `1` then it should return `244`, but at present its considering value of `e` as `1`

```
fiware_s = "abc,xyz"
e = fiware_s.split("_")
print (e)
for i in e:
    count =  len(e)
    print (count)
    if count > 1:
        print("244")
    else:
        print("204")
```

What i am missing in this code. Do i have not converted list to array in above code that is why it is considering it as value one.
I want fiware_s = ["abc","xyz"] and then iterate for loop and count its value ... if value is more than "1" it should return code "244". At present its considering it "abc,xyz" as string and value one.
Please help

Comment: You're splitting the `fiware_s` string on the character `"_"`. Because `fiware_s = "abc,xyz"` however, this results in a `list` of one string: `fiware_s.split("_") -> ["abc,xyz"]`.

Comment: Another issue: you're continually calculating the length of `e`, but that's going to be a constant. It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Furthermore: how are you defining the "value" of `e` exactly? Are you talking about the length of the string, or some other metric by which you're "counting" its value?

Comment: Actualy i want to convert list fiware_s into array and then iterate the array and count its value and if value of count is more than 1 it should return "244". So, how can simply convert it from list of string to array ,ie, fiware_s= ["abc","xyz"] and then apply logic of count on it so that it would return code "244"

Comment: Why do you think that splitting `fiware_s` on the `"_"` character would result in what you want?

Comment: I dont know ... that is why i asked on stackoverflow ... what i have done wrong in above code.... i want fiware_s to convert to array and then iteration using for loop

Comment: You should take a look at the [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) You're trying to split a string based on a character that isn't present in that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, since you want to split your string around the **comma** character

```
e = fiware_s.split(",")
```

The resultant list would be

```
e = ["abc","xyz"]
```

But you said that you want `fiware_s = ["abc","xyz"]`, then simply assign the split value to **fiware_s** variable:

```
fiware_s = fiware_s.split(",")
```

Currently, you are splitting around a non-existent **underscore** character, so it doesn't split the string at all and returns the whole original string as a result. For your existing split logic to work, change the definition of **fiware_s** to:

```
fiware_s = "abc_xyz"
```